# Istio not recognizing Postgres Traffic

Tags: postgresql, istio

I am using postgres installed from a bitnami helm chart in my istio service mesh. I am trying to access this database from outside of the cluster. When I hit the istio gateway that I have configured to allow TCP traffic to postgres in (using the go postgres driver, tested with my postgres db editor), the connection is refused.

Postgres connections are not showing up in the istio gateway proxy logs which indicates that they're not being read by istio as TCP (and therefore istio is not managing).

How do I get istio to recognize this traffic and send it to my postgres service?

Istio is routing http traffic to my other services correctly. Postgres is reachable on a Nodeport, or a [port forward](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) so I know that it is running.

**istio gateway**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-app-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      number: 5432
      name: tcp-postgresql
      protocol: TCP
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: my-tls
    hosts:      
    - "*"
```

**virtual service for postgres**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: postgres-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - my-app-gateway
  tcp:
  - match:
    - port: 5432
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 5432
        host: my-postgresql
```

Postgres and the service it uses were created from the [bitnami helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql). I have verified that they have Istio proxy sidecars injected and running.

I have read that [Istio cannot provide TLS origination for Postgres](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/29761), does this mean that it cannot provide a connection for postgres over TCP at all?